# Assumption on Solve and DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

How to fix this problem I can't get something from this!!

```
Clear["Global`*"]
 eqns = {3/2 (\Gamma - \Lambda) y[x]/x - (3/2 \Gamma - 1) 1/(y[x] x^3) ==(3 \Xi)/2}; 
 Assuming[\Xi > 0 && 1 < \Gamma < 2 && y[x] > 0 && \Lambda > 0,Solve[{eqns , y[1] == 1}, y, x]]
sol = Solve[eqns, y, x]
 y1[x_] = y[x] /. sol[[1]];
y2[x_] = y[x] /. sol[[2]];
DSolve[{y1[x[t]] == x'[t]/x[t]}, x[t], t];
DSolve[{y2[x[t]] == x'[t]/x[t]}, x[t], t];
```

Comment: Change `\Gamma` to `\[Gamma]` , same with  ` \Lambda` and `\Xi`

Comment: What should `Solve[eqns, y, x]` mean? x is not a domain.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to solve `eqns`for `y[x]` !

Try

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqns = {3/2 (\[Gamma] - \[Lambda]) y[x]/x - (3/2 \[Gamma] - 1) 1/(y[x] x^3) == (3 \[Xi])/2} 
sol = Solve[eqns, y[x]] 
y1[x_] = y[x] /. sol[[1]];
y2[x_] = y[x] /. sol[[2]];
DSolve[{y1[x[t]] == x'[t]/x[t]}, x[t], t]
DSolve[{y2[x[t]] == x'[t]/x[t]}, x[t], t]
```

Now your code evaluates!

**addendum**

`Reduce` gives condition to enforce `y[x]>0 && \[Xi] > 0 && 1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && \[Lambda] > 0` :

```
cond1=Reduce[(y[x] > 0 /. sol[[1]] ) && \[Xi] > 0 &&1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && \[Lambda] > 0] // Simplify[#, \[Xi] > 0 && 1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && \[Lambda] > 0] &
(*x < 0 && \[Gamma] < \[Lambda] <= (-8 \[Gamma] + 12 \[Gamma]^2 +3 x^4 \[Xi]^2)/(-8 + 12 \[Gamma])*)
cond2=Reduce[(y[x] > 0 /. sol[[2]] ) && \[Xi] > 0 &&1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && \[Lambda] > 0] // Simplify[#, \[Xi] > 0 && 1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && \[Lambda] > 0] &
(*(\[Lambda] < \[Gamma] && x != 0) || (\[Gamma] < \[Lambda] <= (-8 \[Gamma] + 12 \[Gamma]^2 + 3 x^4 \[Xi]^2)/(-8 + 12 \[Gamma]) && x < 0)*)
```

Comment: My problem is InverseFunction, How to know behavior of y[t]

Comment: @FelipeDura that is not at all what you have asked in your question. You have not mentioned `InverseFunction` even once in your question.